# Vue3 vue-draggable-next configuration issue

Tags: javascript, vuejs3, vuedraggable

I am trying to include all the relevant code only. This is for Vue3 and VueDraggableNext. I want to change the order of the list, not move it between lists.

The following is the template and associated scripting:

```
<template>
  <div class="childBox scripts">
   <draggable
       v-model="data.scriptList"
       element="div"
       class="dragArea"
       item-key="id"
   >
      <template 
        #item="{item}"
        element="div"
        class="selectedItems"
        item-key="id"
        :ref="item.label"
      >
         <span>{{item.label}}</span>
         <span class="remove" v-on:click="removeScript(item.id)"></span>
      </template>
    </draggable>
  </div>
</template>

import {ref} from 'vue';
import VueDraggableNext from 'vue-draggable-next';
    
export default {
  name: 'Scheduler',
  components: {
    Draggable: VueDraggableNext
  },
  setup() {
    const data = ref({
      scriptList: [
       {"id": 3, "label": "Yadda"},
       {"id": 2, "label": "Badda"},
       {"id": 13, "label": "Bing" }
      ]
    });
    
    return {
      data
    };
  },
methods: {
 removeScript: function(id) {
    //code here, but irrelevant.
},
```

Nothing renders in the code above except:

```
 <draggable modelvalue="" element="div" class="dragArea" item-key="id"></draggable>
```

If I replace the draggable section with a v-for, it renders, but of course no draggable action:

```
<div v-for="item in data.scriptList" 
  :key="item.id" 
  class="selectedItems list-group-item"
  :ref="item.label">
  <span>{{ item.label }}</span>
  <span class="remove" v-on:click="removeScript(item.id)"></span>
</div>
```

Comment: Try changing Draggable to draggable in components declaration

Answer (score -1):

It seems to be a typo. You import the component with capital letter D but in the template you use it with a lowercase d. They should be the same - call it draggable in the components declaration.

You also need to import VueDraggableNext as a part of 'vue-draggable-next' so the name needs to be wrapped in curly braces.

```
import { VueDraggableNext } from 'vue-draggable-next';

components: {
  draggable: VueDraggableNext
},

 <draggable
       v-model="data.scriptList"
       element="div"
       class="dragArea"
       item-key="id"
   >
```

Comment: I changed the case before, and did it again, no effect. Still doesn't render, no errors, but doesn't work. I've tried it capitalized or uncapitalized, it doesn't work.

Comment: Your import also needs to be: import { VueDraggableNext } from 'vue-draggable-next';

Comment: Thanks for the attempt, but that isn't it either. I'm pretty sure I'm missing some essential setting on this, I'm not getting any errors, just nothing.

Comment: If there is some other draggable tool that works, I'm all ears too.

Comment: I do have the code from vue-draggable-next running. It does all sorts of work setting up the model if I put breakpoints in it. But when new data gets added to the list none of the breakpoints gets hit. It's as if it doesn't get that the data has changed.

Comment: I created some fake data similar to the real data. It doesn't render that either. It hits breakpoints when it loads, it is running, but isn't working.